# How to add time to "wait" command in tasker

Tags: tasker, music, clock

I am pretty new to tasker app and I am trying to create a profile to turn off music after 30 minutes. So I did this:

```
Profile: App (Music)

Task: MusicAutoOff

T1: Notify

* Title: Music Auto Off

* Actions A1: Wait 5 minutes, A2: Wait 30 minutes

T2: Wait 30 minutes

T3: Media Control

* Cmd: Pause

* Simulate Media Button: On

* App: Music

T4: Notify

* Music Turned Off
```

And all I want to do is wait additional 5mins/30mins before executing next commands when I press those action buttons on notification. How can I do this?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
Tasker XML Project File Added for reference: [MusicAutoOff.xml](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1I2aSmG9V_YeDRnenFobVlYZTg)

SCREENSHOTS:

[image: Task Detail]

Comment: Can you export Your task (as a file) upload it somewhere, and give us the link? It makes it much easier to help you.

Comment: @DanBrown I just uploaded the tasker file for reference

Comment: Tricky, I cannot import your script 'Failed to import profile data.' Are you using a custom scene (if so, send it!)

Comment: I didn't use any custom scene for that profile or task. Anyways i'll add some screenshots of the task and profile to the question.

Comment: I created a separate project for that task and exported to an xml file and update the old file with the new one.

Comment: Huh, alright. You want that wait to last longer, right? Have your tried Tapping it?

Comment: Yes, but that didn't work

Comment: Does the "Music Turned Off" toast ever show up on your phone?